# Create New Table with Conditional Assignments - MS Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, primary-key, create-table

Sample data:

```
ORDER    SEQ    IN      OUT
310      1      Jan-20  Jan-22
310      2      Jan-22  Jan-23
207      1      Jan-23  Jan-26
207      2      Jan-26  Jan-27
207      3      Jan-27  Jan-29
```

I need to create a new table that makes `ORDER` a primary key and assigns each `ORDER` entry a new `IN` and `OUT` value by retrieving the new `IN` value from the lowest `SEQ` of that `ORDER` and the new `OUT` value from the greatest `SEQ` of that `ORDER`.

For example:

```
ORDER    IN      OUT
310      Jan-20  Jan-23
207      Jan-23  Jan-29
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to create a query that uses 'Totals' with GROUP BY on ORDER and then MIN for In and MAX for Out? That gives you the output you need. Then how do you want to create the new table? Manually? Using VBA? Using SQL?

Comment: I will try that, thanks. I wanted to create the new table using SQL. I am confused, what does Totals refer to?

Comment: Here is an example of the SQL to get the results you want: SELECT tblOrder.Order, Min(tblOrder.InDate) AS MinOfInDate, Max(tblOrder.OutDate) AS MaxOfOutDate
FROM tblOrder
GROUP BY tblOrder.Order;

Comment: Example of SQL to make the table (and ditto on the bad field names!!):     strSQL = "CREATE TABLE tblOrderSum (OrderNo INT, InDate DATETIME, OutDate DATETIME, PRIMARY KEY (OrderNo))"
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! What is the proper way of indicating that this solved my issue? since these are comments (I'm new to SO)

Comment: I really don't know what the rules are regarding marking an answer. Quite often things are solved in just the comments so they never get an official answer. If you want, I think you could post your own answer explaining the steps you took to get it to work. Or I could post a summary of the steps. Whatever is fine by me. And thank you for responding and doing this right!! Too often you never see a response when someone finally gets it to work - leaving you to wonder if they gave up.

Comment: I can see you already have an answer in the comments. I am deleting my answer

Comment: <at>cha your edits solved my issue as well, and @dunn I would rather you posted a summary as you could help better than I could, if that's still fine. I could cite it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an aggregation query:

```
select [order], min([in]) as [in], max(out) as out
from sample
group by [order];
```

By the way, `order` and `in` are lousy names for columns because they are a SQL reserved word.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know its an aggregation query. I've changed the column names but now I get the following error: "Circular reference caused by alias 'IN1' in query definition's SELECT list."

Comment: Try naming the output aliases to something else.